# Handling whitespaces in django tooltips while using translations

Tags: django, django-templates

I would like to translate a tooltip on a link with the bootstrap class btn in a django template. It looks something like this:

```
<a href="" class="btn btn-large btn-success" name="phone" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right"title="Edited via phone"></a>
```

This works but I would like to translate the tooltip. If I use one word in English but a string with whitespaces (telefonisch bearbeitet) as a German translation like 
`title={% trans "Edited" %}` It works as well.

What's not working (and that's what I want) are two string with whitespaces in a trans element. It cuts off after the first word.
When I write `title={% trans "Edited via phone" %}` and translate it to "telefonisch bearbeitet" the English tooltip just shows "Edited" and the German tooltip just shows "telefonisch".

I also tried the blocktrans tag and simply can't find a working solution. Translating whitespace seperated strings in general works. It's only this specific case that does not. Does anyone know how I can get this to work?

Comment: You need to wrap the attribute value in quotes, just as you would normally do: `title="{% trans "Edited via phone" %}"`.

Comment: @sayse have done - never really sure whether to answer what is (to me) a debug-type question. I'm sure there is plenty of discussion about this on meta.

Comment: @solarissmoke - its a fine line between a typographical error and what is a misunderstanding of the syntax (upvoted anywho)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to wrap the attribute value in quotes, as you would normally do: `title="{% trans "Edited via phone" %}"`. The `trans` tag does not do that for you.